# How to read Google Play Magazines on iPad iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ipad, google

I'm a long time Android user and have several magazine subscriptions on Google Play Newsstand.

I have a new iPad and installed the Google Play Newsstand App, expecting to be able to read my magazines. But to my dismay, the iOS app does not support "magazines"!!?

The only way I've found so far to read the magazines is via the Google Play website in the Chrome browser (as I would do on my desktop PC), however, the experience on iOS is not good (and inconvenient)! (The text is too small and "zoom" does not work properly, full screen mode does not work, does not remember page, "breaks" if left open in a tab for a period of time (maybe the "session" closes?), etc.)

So, is there a better way to read my Google Play Magazines on iPad iOS 8?

Comment: Did you check if they have a native iOS version? Most online subscriptions have both Android & iOS native versions

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes, there are native iOS versions. But that would involve subscribing and paying twice? Currently I also read on my Android phone and PC (via Chrome on PC it works OK). I am tempted to switch to iOS - but then it's _only_ available on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent update to the Google Play Newsstand App (Version 3.2 - 14 July 2015) has added "Magazine support"!

The experience is pretty much identical to the Android version.